# Duplicate a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, qwidget

I need to be able to copy a Qwidget so I can duplicate a window because it will change during runtime. is this possible?

```
void Duplicate(QWidget * Show)
{
 //I tried...
 Qwidget Shw = *Show; //but operator= is private
 //and the copy constructor (I think), which is also private
 Qwidget Shw(*Show);
 //

 Shw.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is by design. The usual way to solve it is to implement a method (typically called `clone()`) that allows you to specify the exact semantics that should apply when copying instances of your class. This approach also prevents unintentional copies from being made implicitly, e.g by container classes.

From the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details):

> **No copy constructor or assignment operator**
>
> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on [Identity vs Value](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html#identity-vs-value) on the Qt
>   Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that you should use pointers to QObject (or to
>   your QObject subclass) where you might otherwise be tempted to use
>   your QObject subclass as a value. For example, without a copy
>   constructor, you can't use a subclass of QObject as the value to be
>   stored in one of the container classes. You must store pointers.