# error: 'QDialog::QDialog(const QDialog&)' is private

Tags: qt

As the title stands I get this error within content of this snippet:

```
class NewTaskDialog : public QDialog
```

It was working just fine earlier, but error started showing up when I added method:

```
void MainWindow::saveButtonClicked(NewTaskDialog dialogWindow)
```

Comment: You should not be passing a dialog by value use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for `saveButtonClicked` creates a copy of the `NewTaskDialog` that's passed to it. [You can't copy QWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809596/duplicate-a-qwidget) unless you create a cloning function that explicitly provides the exact functionality you seek. QWidget's constructor is private.

You must pass a pointer

```
void MainWindow::saveButtonClicked(NewTaskDialog* dialogWindow)
```

or a reference. Using the pointer is the standard Qt way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to the QDialog instead. The QDialog class has the copy constructor defined as private to try prevent you from passing a QDialog by value since you should never do that.

[What's the use of the private copy constructor in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811037/whats-the-use-of-the-private-copy-constructor-in-c)